# Open database readonly from ZIP file without unpacking

Tags: android, sqlite

I can use for example ZipResourceFile library http://developer.android.com/google/play/expansion-files.html#ZipLib to get InputStream of file with database, but it has constructor 
`SQLiteDatabase openDatabase(String path, CursorFactory factory, int flags);`
and need path to file.
Is it possible to open SQLiteDatabase readonly from ZIP file without unpacking in android?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You will have to unpack the database in any case, whether it is to memory or to the disk. So it really doesn't make much sense to not unpack it to the disk, as that will make your life easier when using such classes.

Comment: I want to use expansion files in my app, with size for example 300mb, which contains few db. According to documentation I can't delete expansion file, and I should unpack it, and it will use +500mb on cd card what is not wery good for user.

Comment: @anber Don't unpack everything. Just unpack your database.

Comment: I have only databases in expansion files. For example images and statistic db, and I need them both.